# Rotation of a vector and general value of angle according to given conditions: how do I find the correct answer among the two?

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

My question states:

For some non-zero vector $\overrightarrow{V}$, if the some of $\overrightarrow{V}$ and the vector obtained by rotating it by $\angle2\alpha$ equals the vector obtained from $\overrightarrow{V}$ by rotating it by an angle of $\angle \alpha$, then the general value of $\angle \alpha$ is?

Here's how I tried it:

Clearly, we can write from the given conditions that, $\overrightarrow{V} + \overrightarrow{V}_{2\alpha}  = \overrightarrow{V}_{\alpha}$

where, $\overrightarrow{V}_\alpha = \overrightarrow{V}$ rotated by angle $\angle \alpha$

$\overrightarrow{V}_{2\alpha} = \overrightarrow{V}$ rotated by angle $\angle 2\alpha$

Also, the magnitudes of each of them are equal, and this yields:

$|\overrightarrow{V} + \overrightarrow{V}_{2\alpha}|^2  = |\overrightarrow{V}_{\alpha}|^2$

From here, I get that $\cos 2\alpha = -\frac{1}{2} \implies 2\alpha = 2n\pi \pm \frac{2\pi}{3}\implies \alpha = n\pi \pm \frac{\pi}{3}$

But, if I used the fact that  $|\overrightarrow{V}_{2\alpha}|^2  = |\overrightarrow{V}_{\alpha} - \overrightarrow{V} |^2$

Then I seem to get that $\cos \alpha = \frac{\pi}{3} \implies \alpha = 2n\pi \pm \frac{\pi}{3}$

Why do I get some more solutions in my approach, and how to understand which one is the correct solution? There must be a way to check right? (The book states that the 2nd answer is correct). What was the error of my approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first approach, you are finding solutions for

$$ \vec V + \vec V_{2\alpha} = \vec V_\alpha  \tag1$$

and also solutions for

$$ \vec V + \vec V_{2\alpha} = -\vec V_\alpha.  \tag2$$

Both Equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ are satisfied by vectors that also satisfy
$$ \lVert\vec V + \vec V_{2\alpha}\rVert^2 = \lVert\vec V_\alpha\rVert^2 $$
(just take the square of the magnitude on each side),
but only Equation $(1)$ is consistent with the requirements of the question.
The solutions of Equation $(2)$ are the incorrect angles
$2n\pi \pm \frac{2\pi}3.$

The second approach can also be written
$$ \lVert\vec V_\alpha - \vec V\rVert^2 = \lVert\vec V\rVert^2
 = \lVert\vec V_\alpha\rVert^2  \tag3$$
since $\lVert\vec V_{2\alpha}\rVert^2 = \lVert\vec V\rVert^2.$
Then since $\vec V,$ $\vec V_\alpha,$ and $\vec V_\alpha - \vec V$
are three sides of a triangle, it is clear that Equation $(3)$ describes an equilateral triangle, one of whose angles is the angle between
$\vec V$ and $\vec V_\alpha,$
which can only be accomplished by rotations through angles
$2n\pi \pm \frac\pi3.$

---

If you only thought of the first approach and don't think of the second one in time, you can still use the first approach, but keep this in mind:

**Beware of squaring both sides of an equation.** Always remember that while it is true that $A=B$ implies $A^2=B^2,$ it is **not** true that $A^2=B^2$ implies $A=B.$ Instead, $A^2=B^2$ implies $A=\pm B,$ so any solutions  you get from $A^2=B^2$ have to be carefully checked to see which ones are the true $A=B$ solutions and which are the false $A=-B$ solutions.

In this particular problem, a vector diagram for $\pm\frac\pi3$ covers all the even $n$ in $n\pi\pm\frac\pi3$ and a diagram for $\pi\pm\frac\pi3$ covers all the odd $n$. All other values of $n\pi\pm\frac\pi3$ can be obtained by adding some multiple of $2\pi$ to one of these examples.
In the second diagram, in fact, it may be easier to construct the angles if you construct the angle $-\pi+\frac\pi3$ rather than $-\pi+\frac\pi3$ for the $+$ case, that is, add $-2\pi$ to that case, while keeping the angle $\pi-\frac\pi3$ for the $-$ case, so that one angle is clockwise and the other counterclockwise.
You might even draw three or four vector diagrams if that's what it takes to cover all the cases without getting confused.

If you examine the case $\alpha = \frac\pi3$ in a vector diagram in which you have constructed $\vec V_\alpha$ and $\vec V_{2\alpha}$ relative to an arbitrary $\vec V,$ it should be clear that this $\alpha$ is a correct answer. Likewise with the case $\alpha = -\frac\pi3$.
But with $\alpha = \pi-\frac\pi3 = \frac{2\pi}3,$ after drawing $\vec V_\alpha$ and $\vec V_{2\alpha}$ relative to an arbitrary $\vec V$ it should be clear that $\vec V + \vec V_{2\alpha}$ points in the wrong direction and cannot be equal to $\vec V_\alpha$.

So you can see graphically that $n\pi\pm\frac\pi3$ gives correct answers only in the cases where $n$ is even, and you can correct the answer by writing $2n$ instead of $n$.

Comment: But I had been getting the answer that $\alpha = n\pi \pm  \frac{\pi}{3}$.

How do I know if that is the wrong answer in an examination environment?

Comment: You have to check your work. I have added some ideas about how you can do that.